# How do I set an environment variable in a YARN Spark job?

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, cloudera-cdh, accumulo

I'm attempting to access [Accumulo 1.6](http://accumulo.apache.org/1.6/apidocs/) from an [Apache Spark](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.0.0/api/java/index.html) job (written in Java) by using an `AccumuloInputFormat` with `newAPIHadoopRDD`. In order to do this, I have to tell the `AccumuloInputFormat` where to locate ZooKeeper by calling the `setZooKeeperInstance` method. This method takes a `ClientConfiguration` object which specifies various relevant properties.

I'm creating my `ClientConfiguration` object by calling the static `loadDefault` method. This method is supposed to look in various places for a `client.conf` file to load its defaults from. One of the places it's supposed to look is `$ACCUMULO_CONF_DIR/client.conf`.

Therefore, I am attempting to set the `ACCUMULO_CONF_DIR` environment variable in such a way that it will be visible when Spark runs the job (for reference, I'm attempting to run in the `yarn-cluster` deployment mode). I have not yet found a way to do that successfully.

So far, I've tried:

- Calling `setExecutorEnv("ACCUMULO_CONF_DIR", "/etc/accumulo/conf")` on the `SparkConf`
- Exporting `ACCUMULO_CONF_DIR` in `spark-env.sh`
- Setting `spark.executorEnv.ACCUMULO_CONF_DIR` in `spark-defaults.conf`

None of them have worked. When I print the environment before calling `setZooKeeperInstance`, `ACCUMULO_CONF_DIR` does not appear.

If it's relevant, I'm using the [CDH5](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cdh5/latest/CDH5-Release-Notes/CDH5-Release-Notes.html) versions of everything.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do (imports and exception handling left out for brevity):

```
public class MySparkJob
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf();
        sparkConf.setAppName("MySparkJob");
        sparkConf.setExecutorEnv("ACcUMULO_CONF_DIR", "/etc/accumulo/conf");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
        Job accumuloJob = Job.getInstance(sc.hadoopConfiguration());
        // Foreach loop to print environment, shows no ACCUMULO_CONF_DIR
        ClientConfiguration accumuloConfiguration = ClientConfiguration.loadDefault();
        AccumuloInputFormat.setZooKeeperInstance(accumuloJob, accumuloConfiguration);
        // Other calls to AccumuloInputFormat static functions to configure it properly.
        JavaPairRDD<Key, Value> accumuloRDD =
            sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(accumuloJob.getConfiguration(),
                               AccumuloInputFormat.class,
                               Key.class,
                               Value.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I discovered the answer to this while writing the question (sorry, reputation seekers). The problem is that CDH5 uses Spark 1.0.0, and that I was running the job via YARN. Apparently, YARN mode does not pay any attention to the executor environment and instead uses the environment variable `SPARK_YARN_USER_ENV` to control its environment. So ensuring `SPARK_YARN_USER_ENV` contains `ACCUMULO_CONF_DIR=/etc/accumulo/conf` works, and makes `ACCUMULO_CONF_DIR` visible in the environment at the indicated point in the question's source example.

This difference in how standalone mode and YARN mode work resulted in [SPARK-1680](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-1680), which is reported as fixed in Spark 1.1.0.